# AutoIdentity is behaving extra erratically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with an `ID` column which is not null and has autoidentity enabled

My problem is that I only insert like 4-5 rows each day with few edits as well but for some reason the `ID` changes by a thousand each day.

So yesterday it was 2004/2005 today I added my first entry: 3004

I highly doubt that I added 1000 records in it.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a known issue due to the changes Microsoft made for SQL Server 2012. The other SO question I linked to also contains some workarounds for this.

Comment: I read the answers but was unable to disable this behaviour even by
 
CREATE SEQUENCE CountBy1 
 START WITH 1 
 INCREMENT BY 1 
 MINVALUE 0 
 NO MAXVALUE 
 NO CACHE ;
GO

Is there an easier way to do that?